# how can I make port forwarding for port 8080?

Tags: apache, wamp, port, portforwarding

I have wamp server on my pc. 
I want to run php files on the apache server. 
But the thing is I cannot make my Apache run on port 80 because of IIS. So I bind Apache to port 8080 and wWhen I use address localhost:8080 it works fine.

But I cannot go through myip:8080, as far as i know i should make port forwardings and actually I did, it works on another laptop of mine when the apache runs on port 80, but on this laptop it doesn't seem to work.

How should I configure my port forwardings? local ip of this laptop is 192.168.0.4,

Comment: Can you clarify please. Are you trying to use `http://192.168.0.4:8080` to run your site from the PC running the WAMP Server, or, are you trying to access your site from outside your localnetwork i.e. the internet?

Comment: actually both, i have my site running on port:8080 i can reach it from localnetwork. and I want to make it available from internet too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if this version of WAMP Server is running on 192.168.0.4 and Listening to port 8080 you will have to port forward port 8080 on your router so that connections coming into your network on 8080 get sent to 192.168.0.4:8080. This should be similiar to what you did for your other wamp server on the other pc but just using port 8080 instead of port 80.

Of course if you are not using the other WAMP Server and you router is capable of this you could forward incoming port 80 on your router to 192.168.0.4:8080. This wouldl make access from the internet easier as users would not have to remember to add :8080 to your routers ip address.

Also remember that you will have to `Put Online` this Wamp Server so access from ip's other than 127.0.0.1 are allowed.

Just as a final thought, have you considered setting up `Named Virtual Hosts` for your 2 sites on the other WAMP Server, the one using port 80 and already working with your existing port forwarding. Virtual Hosts allow you to run multiple sites through one instance of Apache. If this idea interests you, I can send you my HowTo on that, or you can check out the [WAMP Server Forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/list.php?2) its posted on there in a few answers already.